# Memory Allocation in std::map

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, complexity-theory

I am doing a report on the various C++ dictionary implementations (map, dictionary, vectors etc).

The results for insertions using a std::map illustrate that that the performance is O(log n).  There are also consistent spikes in the performance.  I am not 100% sure what's causing this; I think they are caused by memory allocation but I have been unsuccessful in finding any literature / documentation to prove this.

Can anyone clear this matter up or point me in the right direction?

Cheers.

Comment: I think the behavior depends heavily on the implementation (because STL doesn't specify how it should be implemented only how it is to be used).

Comment: @restevens -- that's not right, there's a definition of how the STL should behave (i.e. what the big-O performance of each type of container should be).

Comment: @rstevens: That is wrong. The STL containers are defined in terms of guarantees on the complexity of the different operations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are right: it is O(log n) complexity.  But this is due to the sorted nature of map (normally binary tree based).

Also see http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/UniqueSortedAssociativeContainer.html there is a note on insert.  It’s worst case is O(log n) and amortized O(1) if you can hint where to do the insert.

Maps are normally based on binary trees and need to be balanced to keep good performance.  The load spikes you are observing probably correspond to this balancing process

Comment: I initially thought the spikes were being caused by the tree rotations, but no spikes occur until 50,000 items have been inserted into the map.  After this number the spikes occur consistently (approximately) every 25,000 items after that, each one consistent in magnitude.

Comment: I'm answering late but it might be useful: the balancing can be performed at each insertion, with a minimum amount of operations, so the spikes in my guess are the reallocations that are performed when the amount of memory pre-allocated for elements is reached.

Answer (score 2):

The empirical approach isn't strictly necessary when it comes to STL. There's no point in experimenting when the standard clearly dictates the minimal complexity of operations such as std::map insertion.

I urge you to read the standard so you're aware of the minimal complexity guarantees before continuing with experiments. Of course, there might be bugs in whatever STL implementation you happen to be testing; but the popular STLs are pretty well-debugged creatures and very widely used, so I'd doubt it.

Answer (score 2):

If I remember correctly, std::map is a balanced red-black tree.  Some of the spikes could be caused when the std::map determines that the underlying tree needs balancing.  Also, when a new node is allocated, the OS could contribute to some spikes during the allocation portion.

Comment: GCC implementation of std::map is in fact a red-black tree. I believe MS VS uses a red-black tree as well, but I'm not 100% sure of that. The spikes would most likely be the re-balancing of the tree.